# FLutter :matching Listtile height to card height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[image]I am trying to match the listtile height to the height of the card but listtile height is very small. it has default height which is very small. i want to change it to match the height of the card.please help me.
Following below is my code .

```
 Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: listitems.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(children:<Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 100,
                          child: Card(
                            semanticContainer: true,
                            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,

                            child:ListTile(
                              leading: Image.network('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550251592-aee2da85a87e?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80'),
                            ),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            elevation: 5,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]);
                    }),
              ),
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: ListTile has a default height. What stops you from creating your own listtile with Columns/Rows?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the documentation correctly, ListTile is just a pre-customized composition of a row with a fixed-height. I couldn't figure out what final result you're looking for but I checked your code,

a.Using Container instead of ListTile to set a row/column composition would help you, though I used the container alone and it worked.

b.Try removing the parent container(the one with the height:110), put a Container as the child of the card. (your content can go under the new container instead of listTile).
please tell me if you're looking for a specific result and my answer is irrelevant.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: listitems.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Column(children:<Widget>[
                Card(
                  semanticContainer: true,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                  child:Container(
                    child: Image.network('the image url'),
                  ),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                ),
              ]);
            }),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i tried with row column with expanded widget and i ended up like this

Comment: i have attached the photo which resulted from following below code